# From Field blank while sending email from record

Tags: email, email-template, email-alert, singleemailmessage

One of my users is trying to send an email from a record page. but while sending the email **from** is blank and it's grayed out.
The user is not able to send any email because of this.

I know by adding org-wide email address we can get that option, but I want the user to send an email from his name, not from any other email.
I guess I'm missing some permission.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Is the behaviour same in the Classic experience?

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315645&type=1&mode=1